# How to get the selected row id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I'm trying to use the following JavaScript function to get a particular cell value from a jqgrid upon click.

In the below function `#datagrid` is the table where the jqgrid is stored in.

```
            $("#datagrid").click(function(){ 
                var selr = $("#datagrid").getCol('companyid');
                alert(selr);
            });
```

My problem is when I click the jqgrid it will show ALL row id's from the jqgrid in the alert message, but I only need a particular companyid which was selected from the jqgrid. How do I make this work?

Comment: Add HTML code or a piece of it.

Comment: Have you referred this page? - http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getCell` function to read the value from the cell identified by row id.

So, You should try something like this:

```
$("#datagrid").click(function(){ 
    var grid = jQuery('#datagrid');
    var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    var myCellData = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'MyColName');
});
```

Comment: if i click first time on jqgrid it gives false.then i clicked another row ,now i get the row id which is clicked previous row's id