# Multiselect in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using a JQGrid, and have designed the grid such that the first column is a checkbox. I am using the property of `multiselect:true`, and I am not writing any code other than this to get the checkboxes. How do I fetch the values from the rows where the checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 3):

To get the selected rows, use:

```
var selected = $("#tableid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
```

`selected` will be set to an array of IDs of the selected rows.

To get column values from the rows, use the `getCell` method. See [How to get the selected row id in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242825/how-to-get-the-selected-row-id-in-javascript?lq=1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply... am getting the ids in a comma separated array. what if i want to get the 1st column values in the same way?

Comment: But that is returning me only 1 value. if i have 5 columns selected in multiselect only last value is shown. But i need all the values of the corresponding checkbox selected.

Comment: You need to iterate over the array and do what you want with each row.